# How to enable flashlight from an apple watch complication

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch.app

Using an Apple Watch SE series 44-mm (Model: A2352), is it possible to set the flashlight function as a complication?

Maybe using built in functions, Shortcuts or [Watchsmith](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/watchsmith/id1483088503)?

I'm using the Infograph Modular face.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with built-in apps.

**Shortcuts** has a **Set Flashlight** actions, but I've tried it and it doesn't work on the Apple Watch.

You might find a 3rd-party app to do it.